# Single I2S Source for Two Speaker Amplifier

Tags: i2s

I have two same speaker amplifier which is TAS5720 series from TI.
I drawn two identical schematics for these ICs which driven by one I2S source.
In practise, one of them is playing sound bad. Both of two has correct duty cycle at output stage and one of them is modulating depending on digital sound data but the broken one could not modulate. If I only initialize the broken one by software. It plays sound well.

> This is my schematic.

[image: 2s]

Comment: You say they are identical schematics, how are you able to configure them over I2C without conflict?

Comment: @ChrisStratton 14.pin specifies the adress by pulling high or low. I mean passive components and I2S pins are identical. I2C addresses are different of course.

Comment: What is the source?  What have you done to verify that its I2S output is the same in both cases?  What is the power supply?  Define "badly"?   Think about the various ways that the problem unit could "know" that the other one has been configured or not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Same sound are coming from speakers but the one's sound was cracking. This IC gets digital data and does some operations ( like boosting and clippering) after that converts these digital data to PWM outputs. These pwm signals drive FET's of full bridges. Both of amplifier have correct PWM signal at the front of inductors. Duty cycles of  pwm signals which is belongs to broken one was not changings correctly depending on incoming data and sound was muffling. Meanwhile, the other one was playing correctly. If I do not init the IC which works correctly, broken one works well.

Comment: Is the digital content of the I2S stream *identical* even if only one chip is configured?  Or does the source **which you neglected to identify** change behavior based on how many you configure?   Does the *analog* character *of* the digital I2S stream change?  Do you perhaps have a signal integrity problem there?  What about the power supply **which again you did not identify** - if you modify things so they have distinct supplies or more supply caps, does that help?  Again, focus on any way that the problem one could even "know" that the other is configured.

Comment: Always same data streams by I2S. Drivers of IC are written by OOP method and configurations are same. There is one anolog line to supplies both of speakers. I will share pcb design tomorrow. I2S line stay same just do not init IC. I wonder that could it be possible to drive multiple IC in one single I2S?

Comment: How do you actually know that the I2S signals are the same, in terms of both their digital data and the analog waveform by which they *approximate* a digital signal?  Can you configure one chip to operate but be muted and then see how the other behaves?  Or turn its volume way down?